# I am unable to copy/paste lots of files from a NTFS 4TB external drive, to a SSD 16TB USB stick to back up the 4TB drive. Always fails except for?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup, external-hard-drive, copy

I have a WD 4TB external USB storage dive, that I want to copy everything on it to a newly purchased 16TB USB SSD stick drive.
I started to copy/paste all of the data (about 860GB) which took quite a while to get through, while it was running I was getting pop up messages saying that some file properties could not be copied.

After it had finished I found that most of the files were unplayable.
I did some research mostly here and online, where I was pointed to the properties and found that the WD drive was NTFS, and the SSD was FAT32 - and then I learned that that was the fail point.

However, I changed the SSD to an NTFS format, but I am still getting failed attempts at a bulk copy - that is they copy across and I can see them, but when I attempt to open them with media player I get 0xc10100bf, and nothing with VLC player either. That is unless I copy a file at a time.

I found that if I copy 1 file across, then verify it on the new drive it works perfectly.
Am I destined to copy everything one by one?
Is there a way to do it by grabbing and pasting?

Comment: Leading question… how much did it cost?

Comment: It will be a fake drive.

Comment: ↑ hence the leading question ;) you *can* get 16TB SSDs, but they're about 3,000 bucks. eBay has them on offer for 20. Spot the difference. See https://www.zdnet.com/article/samsung-galaxy-tab-s8-plus-review/ for an SD card reader. Hope you bought it from somewhere you can return it & report the seller for fraud.

Comment: drive performs exactly like a HDD - properties say capacity 16,777,215,995,904 bytes 15.2TB free it was an Ebay purchase https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/224756759830?var=523615282759

Comment: It doesn't matter at all what properties says, if it's being lied to. See https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/

Comment: I have added the Ebay link to it $57

Comment: Yup, about 2,800 dollars short of what one really costs. You've been ripped off. This is a real one - https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/reviews/16tb-sabrent-rocket-xtrm-q-ssd-review

Comment: Thanks for the info - I did get it through PayPal so I have some backup to assist. I will try those checking programs to gauge the extent of fraud then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

So this is **not** 16TB SSD. It is of some "usual" capacity, but with patched firmware to show up as 16TB. Notice its somewhat "almost exact" capacity (in megabytes): 16777216 = 2²⁴; I had never seen real devices that have such precise "binary-bounded" capacity.

You can try to write a pattern to a whole drive, sector by sector, and then try to read it back — you won't read the thing you wrote, plus you'll know what's the real capacity. It either will wrap, or read some sectors as garbage (0x00's, 0xff'x, like that).

As it was mentioned in comments, the price of 16TB SSD should be around $3000, certainly not $57.

Open complaint.